# Find duplicates in string, and return single result for only duplicates

Tags: python, string

I've seen many examples on here, but I haven't been able to find one that fits my scenario.

I'm trying to take a string like:

```
string = "Hi my Name is Bill, Bill likes coding, coding is fun"
```

and return only, **1** value for each duplicate.

So the output would be like (ignoring punctuation):

```
Bill
coding
```

How can I accomplish this in `Python3`

Comment: and what about "is"?

Comment: You can use a `set` to do this. What does your code look like so far?

Comment: @HåkenLid using a `set` would probably be confusing, since that would remove duplicates, and therefor the count information necessary to get the OPs desired results. Unless I'm overlooking a different way to use `set`s, in which case please elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split your string into words.  There are different ways of doing this, depending on requirements.  Here's one way:

```
words = re.findall('\w+', string)
```

Count the frequency of the words:

```
word_counts = collections.Counter(words)
```

Get all the words that appear more than once:

```
result = [word for word in word_counts if word_counts[word] > 1]
```

Comment: That's a great solution , I limit myself to ```str.split``` and try to replace punctuation first . Thx for sharing solution .

Comment: or maybe `result = [word for word, count in word_counts.items() if count > 1]`? Not too much more concise, but now it doesn't need to re-do the `word_counts` lookup. Otherwise, great answer - I was hoping there was a `Counter` in these solutions or I was gonna post one :)

Comment: @dwanderson: The main reason I avoided `items()` is that I didn't know whether this is Python 2 or 3.  In Python 2, I'd prefer to use `iteritems()`, though it doesn't really matter.  The way I wrote it I just didn't have to think about it.

Comment: Ah, I was gonna edit my comment to mention `iteritems()` if it was python2, but got lazy. fair enough then; again, I'm sure the difference is negligible unless it's some absurdly large dictionary, and even then I don't know how things work under the hood (and calling `.items()` in py2 would then be very wasteful). I accept your justification (for whatever that's worth, i.e. `0`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) after you split your string to all the words and then print only the words that appear more than once (`count > 1`):

```
>>> import collections
>>> import re
>>> string = "Hi my Name is Bill, Bill likes coding, coding is fun"
>>> words = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  string).split()
>>> word_counts = collections.Counter(words)
>>> for word, count in word_counts.items():
        if count > 1:
            print word
```

Outputs:

```
is
Bill
coding
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use https://github.com/Alir3z4/python-stop-words

and then 
import collections
from stop_words import get_stop_words
stop_words = get_stop_words('english')
s = "Hi my Name is Bill, Bill likes coding, coding is fun"
words = s.split()
word_map = {}
for word in words:
    word = word.strip().replace(',','')
    if word not in stop_words:
       word_map[word] = word_map.get(word,0)+1
for word,count in word_map.items():
    if count>1:
       print word
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` to replace punctuation

```
import string
import re


text = "Hi my Name is Bill, Bill likes coding, coding is fun"

regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
out = regex.sub(' ', text)
```

Use `Counter` to count :

```
from collections import Counter

out = out.split()

counter = Counter(out)

ans = [i[0] for i in counter.items() if i[1] >1]

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got this right you want to filter out duplicates? if so you can do this.

```
string = "Hi my Name is Bill, Bill likes coding, coding is fun"
string = string.replace(',' , '')
string = list(set(string.split()))
string = '\n'.join(string)
print(string)
```

Comment: I just ran it on my terminal and it worked, what error is it giving you?

Comment: It runs fine, it just doesn't get rid of duplicates nor does it print the duplicates... (which was the requirement)

Comment: oh, sorry about that haven't had my morning cup of joe xD

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex to find out the proper words neglecting punctuations, try this

```
import re
import collections
sentence="Hi my Name is Bill, Bill likes coding, coding is fun"
wordList = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  sentence).split()
print [item for item, count in collections.Counter(wordList).items() if count > 1]
```

and collections should do the trick of finding out repetitions.

Comment: So... exactly my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def result(x): #input should be the string
    repeated = []
    listed = x.split()
    for each in listed:
        number = listed.count(each)
        if number > 1:
            repeated.append(each)

    return set(repeated) #there can't be repeated values in a set
```